# ASP.Net Core API 3.1 JsonPatch not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, patch

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 API, which uses by default System.Text.Json for Json serialization, but now I have a requirement to develop a PATCH operation.

I'm trying to achieve the following contract, that was delivered like this by design:

```
    {
    "items":[
      {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/name",
        "value": "Customer name"
      }
    ]
}
```

On Startup I added the following piece of code:

```
private static NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter GetJsonPatchInputFormatter()
    {
        var builder = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddMvc()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(_ => _.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset)
            .Services.BuildServiceProvider();

        return builder
            .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>()
            .Value
            .InputFormatters
            .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>()
            .First();
    }
```

Then I have the following classes to represent my request:

```
public class UpdateCustomerRequest
{
    public JsonPatchDocument<CustomerPatchDocument> Items { get; set; }
}


public class CustomerPatchDocument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, my controller:

```
[HttpPatch]
    [Route("{customerId}")]
    [SwaggerOperation("UpdateCustomer")]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.MultiStatus)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCustomer(Guid customerId, [FromBody] UpdateCustomerRequest request)
    {

    }
```

The thing is that I'm unable to provide a request as represented on the specification.

If I send a request like on the first sample above, this happens:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1[Sonae.Pss.Presentation.Services.WebAPI.Controllers.CustomerPatchDocument]. Path: $.items | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 10.
```

Is it possible to achieve what is requested by the spec using JsonPatchDocument?

Thank you

Comment: any specific reason to wrap `JsonPatchDocument<CustomerPatchDocument>` inside a class ?

Comment: Yes, like I've told, spec requires so. In the meantime I've solved it, it was missing AddNewtonsoftJson() after AddControllersAndViews

Comment: Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1),  to add support for JSON Patch using Newtonsoft.Json. And you can see"The System.Text.Json-based input formatter doesn't support JSON Patch. "from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-support-for-json-patch-when-using-systemtextjson)